# Existence of an exhaustion with intrinsically-bounded regular domains

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, it is possible to find an exhaustion $(U_i)_{i \ge 0}$ of $M$ with regular domains, i.e. with open relatively compact subsets having smooth boundary. Unfortunately, these domains may be **un**bounded in their intrinsic distances, i.e. in the distance produced by $g \big| _{U_i}$ (even though they are bounded in the Riemannian distance of $M$). (Think of $\mathbb R^2$ and take $U = (0,1)^2 \setminus C$ where $C$ is something like an [intricated deleted double comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space), but with the segments of the comb being of constant length $3/4$ and thickness $2^{-n}$, with their thickness decreasing to the left: as a length-metric space $U$ is unbounded to the left.)

> Is it possible to choose this exhaustion having the supplementary property that each $U_i$ is bounded in its intrinsic distance?

Comment: You mean : $M=\mathbb{R}^2,\ M=\bigcup\ U_i$ where each $U_i$ is relatively compact and for any given $j$, there are infinite sequence $p_i,\ q_i\in \partial U_j$ having at least distance $i$ wrt the intrinsic metric in $\partial U_j$ ?

Comment: @HKLee: I mean $M$ arbitrary ($\mathbb R^2$ was used to just illustrate the problem). Each $U_i$ has a a Riemannian tensor $g_i$ - the restriction of $g$ to $U_i$. This $g_i$ produces a distance $d_i$ in the usual way: the infimum of the lengths of all the curves joining the two points. We have $d_i \ge d$, and in principle $d_i$ may be unbounded. Can we choose things in such a way as to make each $d_i$ bounded on $U_i$?

Answer (score 0):

There exists $1$-net $p_i\in M$ i.e., for any $x\in M$, there is some $p_i$ s.t. $d_M(p_i,x)\leq 1$.

Define $V_j =\{ x\in M| d_M(x,p_j)\leq d_M(x,p_k)$ for all $k\neq j\}$, which is contained in a closed ball $B(p_j,1)$.

Define $U_1=V_1$ and $$U_i = \bigcup_{V_j\cap U_{i-1}\neq \emptyset}\ V_j$$

Since $V_j$ is locally finite covering, so we can make $U_i'$ with smooth boundary s.t. $d_H(U_i',U_i)\leq 1$ where $d_H$ is Hausdorff metric.

[Add] For $x_i\in U_i$, there is $p_j$ s.t. $d_M(p_j,x_i)\leq 1$.

In further, $V_j$ has intersection point with $x_{i-1}$ with
$U_{i-1}$.

Hence by reindexing, $$ [x_ip_i]\cup [p_i x_{i-1}]\cup [x_{i-1}p_{i-1}]\cdots\cup[x_1p_1] $$ has a length $ 2i-1
$.

That is, any two points in $U_i$ has at most distance
$4i-2$.

Comment: I see the problem. I rewrite my answer.

Comment: How does it follow that $U'_i$ has bounded *intrinsic* distance?

Comment: I add more explanation.

Comment: You keep making the same mistake over and over again: I am not asking about the distance induced on $U_i$ by the distance on $M$ (this would be trivial: since $U_i$ is relatively compact, it is obviously bounded in the distance $d_M$), I am asking about the [**intrinsic** distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric), which is a totally different thing. The instrinsic distance on $U_i$ is generally **not** the restriction to $U_i$ of $d_M$.

Comment: Yes. You are right. And I modified.